# Why registerTempTable removes some rows from the data-frame?

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

I try to create a pandas data-frame using a Spark data-frame on HDInsight in the following way:

```
tmp = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sparkDf)
tmp.registerTempTable('temp')
```

It looks like the `registerTempTable` removes some rows from the data-frame.

The following command returns 11000

```
sparkDf.count()
```

While `tmp` has only 2500 rows.

I am following steps described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-apache-spark-custom-library-website-log-analysis/).

Comment: What code did you use to count tmp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you're using Jupyter notebooks, and that you're getting your data from a SQL query, i.e.

```
%%sql -o tmp
SELECT * FROM temp
```

This is happening because the `%%sql` query transparently limits the size of the result dataframe `tmp` to 2500 rows.  You can choose a new limit by using the `-n` option:

```
%%sql -o tmp -n 11000
SELECT * FROM temp
```

You can also choose `-1` to say that you don't want to limit the size of the dataframe at all (be careful with this, because if the result set is big enough it can cause your driver to run out of memory or your browser to hang/crash when rendering charts):

```
%%sql -o tmp -n -1 
SELECT * FROM temp
```